# How to import database in Yii2, update rows that have changed, delete rows that have been removed

Tags: mysql, yii2

There are many modules which import and export database. e.g. https://github.com/Beaten-Sect0r/yii2-db-manager

But they, can't update rows or delete or create rows if importable database differ to current database. These modules are just replace database without checking changes in database.

How I can solve or where I can find out info about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic solution that will merge two different databases. Every database is different and such merge should be handled differently. And usually this is not possible, because conflicts cannot be resolved automatically.

You should assume that your databases are unmergable and always treat them as separate environments. For changes that should be done on every instance you should write [migrations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations) and run on every installation.